# Consecutive coupon collection

Tags: probability, expectation, coupon-collector

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290582) has remained unanswered. In its edited form, it asks for a lower bound on the expected number of draws required to collect all coupons in a modified [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem) in which draws can yield more than one coupon and the coupon types within one draw are consecutive.

I was hoping to show that for small consecutive draws (low $q$ in the linked question) the expected number of coupons drawn is bounded below by the expected number of coupons drawn in the standard coupon collector's problem, but to my surprise simulations showed that this is actually an *upper* bound. This is clear enough for large consecutive draws – in the extreme case in which every draw contains all $n$ coupons, we need to draw only $n$ coupons instead of $O(n\log n)$, and if every draw contains $n/2$ consecutive coupons, this is still clearly favourable, but intuitively I would have expected draws of just two consecutive coupons to be unfavourable, since they "explore the sample space" more slowly. The simulations show, however, that even in this case there's a slight improvement.

> Can we prove that tending to collect consecutive coupons reduces the expected number of coupons drawn?

I intentionally phrased the question somewhat vaguely so you can use whatever "tendency to collect consecutively" might allow a proof; if you want a concrete model, you can use either the one in the linked question, where the number of consecutive coupons drawn in each draw is geometrically distributed, or you could draw a fixed number $k$ of consecutive coupons in each draw. For both cases, simulations show that the expected number of coupons drawn is reduced compared to the standard coupon collector's problem.

Comment: The simplest heuristic is that after collecting $b$ batches or $k$ distinct coupons, expected proportion of uncollected coupon will be $(1-\frac k n)^b<(1-\frac 1{n})^{kb}$ - that proportion for $kb$ separate coupons.

Comment: @A.S.: I believe this would be the case if we had $b$ batches of $k$ coupons that are always drawn together in the same batch. But the improvement in the simulations is not nearly as high as in that case. For instance, for $100$ coupons, the standard problem takes $100H_{100}\approx519$, the problem with fixed batches of $2$ coupons ($50$ possible pairs) that I believe you're describing takes $100H_{50}\approx450$, and the problem with variable batches of $2$ coupons ($100$ possible pairs) takes $\sim511$ in the simulation, just $10\%$ of the speedup.

Comment: I'm considering $b$ batches of $k$ consecutive coupons ($n$ choices) above. Very crudely, $$\left(1-\frac k n\right)^{\frac{ET_k}k}\approx\left(1-\frac 1{n}\right)^{ET_1}$$ $$ET_k\approx\frac{k\log(1-\frac 1 n)}{\log(1-\frac k n)}ET_1\approx \left(1-\frac{k-1}{2n}\right)ET_1$$ which yields a $0.5\%$ difference between $ET_2$ and $ET_1$ for $n=100$. Your simulation, OTOH, yields $1.5\%$ difference.

For an exact answer to the highlighted question, consider congruence classes $\mod k$. Each class gets filled in expected $\frac n kH_{\frac n k}$ time, hence $$ET_k<nH_{\frac n k}<nH_n=ET_1$$

Comment: @A.S.: That's a great argument -- if you post it as an answer I'd accept it. I still don't understand the first part though -- why is the first equation not the one for fixed batches of $k$ consecutive coupons ($n/k$ choices)? How would that equation differ?

Comment: Each bucket is covered by $k$ (out of $n$) choices of consecutive $k$ coupons. Hence probability that a batch doesn't cover a given bucket is $(1-\frac k n)$. Raise it to number of batches $b$ to get probability that a given bucket is empty after $b$ batches. Is that clearer? // I'm trying to get an actual estimate on $ET_k$. If you have some other Monte Carlo data (say for $k=2$ and larger $n$), post it, as it can inspire/direct some low $k$ result.

Comment: @A.S.: OK -- but that same argument can be made for the fixed batches (so it makes sense that the result you got from it was somewhere in between those two cases). // More data for $k=2$:

\begin{array}{c|cc}
n&100&200&300&400&500\\\hline
ET_2&510.8±0.1&1164.2±0.2&1870.4±0.3&2611.4±0.4&3378.1±0.5\\
\end{array}

Comment: I'm afraid my direct argument doesn't hold. I counted the number of *batches* but we need to multiply it by $k$ to get a number of *coupons* and that easily breaks the inequality. $ET_k$ should still be decreasing and expected vacancies kind of point to it, but it's not tight // I now see that expectation is the same for $\frac n k$ fixed batches  of size $k$. Didn't think of it before.

Comment: @A.S.: Another way of stating why your direct argument doesn't hold is that you're only counting the coupons in each congruence class as long as that class is still collecting; you're missing the ones that are drawn unnecessarily for the class that's finished before the other one.